# iOS Enterprise option for distributing apps

Tags: ios

When distributing apps using the Apple Developer Enterprise option, can a single iOS device have apps from two different Apple Developer Enterprise profiles?

We found this article stating it can not be done.
http://mobiledan.net/2012/03/02/5-options-for-distributing-ios-apps-to-a-limited-audience-legally/

I contacted Apple Developer support directly and they did not have an answer of yes or no, but they could not find any documentation about this scenario. They did state that MDM could be used to limit apps that can be installed. But there is no reason to believe you can't install apps from two different Enterprise developer profiles.

Does anyone have first hand info about this scenario? The article makes us question this.

Thank you

Comment: Yes they can, I'm developer enterprise app for two different company and have them both installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The enterprise account simply allows you to create a signed and trusted application.  This takes the place of an application signed by Apple.

The only sticking point here is in the license agreement for an enterprise account.  The devices eligible to run an enterprise app are very limited - essential only allowed on employee devices.  So it would be rare to have a person that is employed by multiple companies with enterprise accounts.

The ipa for the app contains the provisioning profile registered with Apple to certify the app.  There is nothing associated the device with that enterprise account such as the way an AdHoc device is registered with a particular account.

Here is a link to a similar answer as well
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/141662/different-enterprise-signed-apps-on-same-ios-device